# Possible Inheritance Scope Issue:

Tags: c++, inheritance, scope

I have an `Array class` that is inheriting from `BaseArray class`. In `BaseArray`, I have the protected member variables `data_` and `cur_size_`. The `Array` class introduces a `resize` function. The problem I am encountering is that none of the protected member variables from `BaseArray` are seeming to be accessed in the `resize` function.

EDIT: Solved the `max_size_` problem, but the `cur_size_` and `data_` file persists

Inheritance? Scope? Help?

The Error:

```
In file included from Array.h:41:0,
                 from driver.cpp:6:
Array.cpp: In member function ‘void Array<T>::resize(size_t)’:
Array.cpp:29:5: error: ‘data_’ was not declared in this scope
     data_=data_;
     ^
Array.cpp:30:18: error: ‘cur_size_’ was not declared in this scope
     if (new_size>cur_size_)
                  ^
Array.cpp:37:5: error: ‘cur_size_’ was not declared in this scope
     cur_size_=new_size;
     ^
```

The Code:

BaseArray.h:

```
#ifndef _BASEARRAY_H_
#define _BASEARRAY_H_

#include <cstring>          

template <typename T>
class BaseArray
{
public:
  /// Type definition of the element type.
  typedef T type;
  //constructors, destructor and methods…
protected:
  /// Pointer to the actual data. m
  char * data_;

  /// Current size of the BaseArray.
  size_t cur_size_;

};

#include "BaseArray.inl"
#include "BaseArray.cpp"

#endif   // !defined _BASEARRAY_H_
```

Array.h:

```
#ifndef _ARRAY_H_
#define _ARRAY_H_

#include <cstring>
#include "BaseArray.h"
template <typename T>
class Array: public BaseArray<T> //inheriting from BaseArray
{
public:
  /// Type definition of the element type.
  typedef T type;

  /// Default constructor.
  Array (void);

  Array (const Array & arr);

  /// Destructor.
  ~Array (void);
  const Array & operator = (const Array & rhs);

  void resize (size_t new_size);

private:
  size_t max_size_; //introduces max_size
};

#include "Array.inl"
#include "Array.cpp"

#endif   // !defined _ARRAY_H_
```

Array.cpp:

```
#include "BaseArray.h"
#include "Array.h"
#include <stdexcept>     
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
Array <T>::Array (void): BaseArray<T>()

{
    std::cout<<"Array def const called"<<std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
Array <T>::Array (const Array & array): BaseArray<T>(array)
{
}

template <typename T>
Array <T>::~Array (void)
{
}


template <typename T>
void Array <T>::resize (size_t new_size)
{
this->data_= this->data_;
if (new_size>this->cur_size_)
    {
    max_size_ = new_size-this->cur_size_-1;
    this->cur_size_=new_size;
    for (max_size_; max_size_<=new_size; max_size_++)
        this->data_[max_size_]=0;
    }
this->cur_size_=new_size;   

}

/* Also tried it like this:

template <typename T>
void Array <T>::resize (size_t new_size)
{
    BaseArray<T>::data_= BaseArray<T>::data_;
    if (new_size>BaseArray<T>::cur_size_)
        {
        max_size_ = new_size-BaseArray<T>::cur_size_-1;
        BaseArray<T>::cur_size_=new_size;
        for (max_size_; max_size_<=new_size; max_size_++)
            BaseArray<T>::data_[max_size_]=0;
        }
    BaseArray<T>::cur_size_=new_size;   
} */
```

Comment: Unrelated note: Why are you including .cpp files in your headers? Don't do that - if you want to compile multiple .cpp files into a single executable, first create object files and link them to create an executable.

Answer (score 2):

**regarding the first error**, you have no max_size() member declared in Array.

**regarding the second error**, name lookup in templates follows a two stage logic, where non dependent expressions are looked up at definition point, whereas dependent expressions are looked up at instantiation point;

This means that when the compiler sees `data_` it thinks it's a variable located somewhere else; at best, it won't find it giving you an error, at worst, it will give you the wrong variable !

In order to solve the problem, you need to make that a dependent expression, the most obvious way being replacing all `data_` with `this->data_`, etc...

**regarding your code organization**, define your templates into a single header file; if you really want to split member implementations place them in a single file with a sensible file extension ( inl is ok, cpp is not )...

Comment: Ok, got the first error solved, thank you. You mention a `base_` but I am not sure where that is at. I went ahead and changed the `resize` function to include `this->`, and also tried a version with `BaseArray<T>::`. While they both compile, testing with a driver file containing a main function to call the resize gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: @cparks10 yes, your resize function has logical problems too .. but, this is off topic ...

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing the error in the logic. Could you point to a specific problem?

Comment: @cparks10 to begin with, data_ is allocated nowhere yet you access it, this is undefined behavior and will probably sigfault when run...

Comment: In my `BaseArray.cpp` file I have an initialization list set up that sets `data_` and `cur_size_` to 0. This should allocate the data right?